LSTM Limitations for Time Series Forecasting
I am working on a project where I generate synthetic data which is the sum of 5 random sine functions sampled every 0.01s (and I add mean reverting brownian motion noise to the data).
# Function parameters
nSines = 5 # Number of sines in the linear combination
amplitude_dist = (0, 1)  # Mean, Std for normal distribution
frequency_dist = (0, 1)  # Mean, Std for normal distribution
phase_dist = (0, 2 * np.pi)  # Min, Max for uniform distribution

# Supervise learning parameters
lookback = 1500
forecast = 300
timesteps = 1500+300 # each spaced delta_t apart
delta_t = 0.01 # time between samples
decay_rate = 0.02
assert timesteps == lookback + forecast

nFunctions = 1000
noise_lvl = 1

print(f'Time between each sample is {delta_t}')
print(f'Number of seconds per function is 
    {delta_t*(lookback+forecast)}')

Generating Univariate Random Sine Functions
$f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k{A_{in}\sin({B_{in}x+C_{in}}})+\sigma*W_n(x)$

$x = $ 0, 0.01, 0.02, ... timesteps-1/100 (x = time in seconds)
$A_{in} $~$ N(0,1)$
$B_{in} $~$ N(0,1)$
$C_{in} $~$ Unif(0,2*\pi)$
$W_n(x)$ = geometric brownian motion. $W_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^x{\hat{Z_j}}*e^{-\lambda*(t-j)}$
$\hat{Z_j}$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$ i.i.d

def generate_random_sines(n, k_sines, timesteps, delta_t, amplitude_dist, frequency_dist, phase_dist, noise_lvl=0.01, 
    decay_rate=0.2):
    """
    Generates n of random linear combinations of k_sines sine functions with added Brownian motion.

    Parameters:
    - n (int): Number of different functions to generate.
    - k_sines (int): Number of sine functions to combine in each sample.
    - timesteps (int): Total number of time steps in each sine wave.
    - delta_t (float): Time step interval.
    - amplitude_dist (tuple): Distribution parameters for amplitude (mean, std).
    - frequency_dist (tuple): Distribution parameters for frequency (mean, std).
    - phase_dist (tuple): Distribution parameters for phase shift (min, max).
    - noise_lvl (float): Size of GBM noise to add

    Returns:
    - t (numpy.ndarray): Array of timestamps for each value with shape (timesteps); each function has the same time start and end
    - data (numpy.ndarray): Array of generated sine waves with shape (n, timesteps).
    """
    data = []
    noNoiseData = []
    noDecayData = []

    for _ in range(n): #creating n functions
        # Generate time array
        t = np.linspace(0, (timesteps - 1) * delta_t, timesteps)
        
        # Initialize signal as zero to sum over multiple sine components
        signal = np.zeros(timesteps)
        
        for _ in range(k_sines):
            # Generate random parameters for a single sine wave
            amplitude = np.random.normal(*amplitude_dist)
            frequency = np.random.normal(*frequency_dist)
            phase_shift = np.random.uniform(*phase_dist)

            # Add the sine component to the signal
            signal += amplitude * np.sin(frequency * t + phase_shift)

        # Add Brownian motion noise
        # Using additive noise here instead of exponential scaling
        brownian_motion = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(delta_t), timesteps)
        noDecayData.append(signal + np.cumsum(brownian_motion))
        
        #adding turning into gbm with mean reversion:
        for i in range(1,timesteps):
            brownian_motion[i] = brownian_motion[i]+brownian_motion[i-1]*np.exp(-decay_rate)

        # noNoiseData.append((signal-np.min(signal))/(np.max(signal)-np.min(signal)))
        noNoiseData.append(signal)
        # noDecayData.append((brownian_signal-np.min(brownian_signal))/(np.max(brownian_signal)-np.min(brownian_signal)))
        noise_signal = signal + noise_lvl*brownian_motion
        # scaled_signal = (noise_signal - np.min(noise_signal))/(np.max(noise_signal)-np.min(noise_signal))
        data.append(noise_signal)

    return t, np.array(data), np.array(noNoiseData), np.array(noDecayData)

t, data, noNoiseData, noDecayData = generate_random_sines(n=nFunctions, 
                                   k_sines=nSines, timesteps=timesteps,
                                   delta_t=delta_t, 
                                   amplitude_dist=amplitude_dist, frequency_dist=frequency_dist, phase_dist=phase_dist,
                                   noise_lvl=noise_lvl, decay_rate=decay_rate)

#Convert so that data is in shape (nSamples,timesteps,features)
data = data[:,:,np.newaxis]
noNoiseData = noNoiseData[:,:,np.newaxis]
noDecayData = noDecayData[:,:,np.newaxis]
print(data.shape)

# Visualize one of the generated sine waves with Brownian noise
data_idx = 5
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(np.arange(timesteps) * delta_t, data[data_idx], label='Random Sum of Sines with Brownian Motion')
plt.plot(np.arange(timesteps) * delta_t, noNoiseData[data_idx], label='Random Sum of Sines No Noise')
plt.plot(np.arange(timesteps) * delta_t, noDecayData[data_idx], label='Random Sum of Sines No Decay')
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Signal Value")
plt.title("Random Sum of Sines with Brownian Motion")
plt.legend()
plt.show()



This is how I create my training and testing data
def train_test_split(data, lookback_period, forecast_period, split = 0.2):
    # rescaling: NOTE ONLY USING Training data for rescaling NOT testing set otherwise leakage
    nTr = int(data.shape[0]*(1-split)) # number of training samples
    # Apply Min-Max Scaling
    
    # data_min = data[:nTr].min(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # shape: (1, 1, features)
    # data_max = data[:nTr].max(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # shape: (1, 1, features)
    # data = (data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min) #scaling

    # standard Z scaling: data - mean/variance
    # data_mean = data[:nTr].mean(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # shape: (1, 1, features)
    # data_std = data[:nTr].std(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # shape: (1, 1, features)
    # data = (data - data_mean) / data_std #scaling
    
    # Apply robust scaling
    data_median = np.median(data[:nTr], axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # shape: (1, 1, features)
    data_25 = np.percentile(data[:nTr], 25, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # 25th percentile
    data_75 = np.percentile(data[:nTr], 75, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)  # 75th percentile
    data_iqr = data_75 - data_25
    data = (data - data_median) / data_iqr #scaling

    
    xTr = data[:nTr,:lookback_period]
    yTr = data[:nTr,lookback_period:]
    xTe = data[nTr:,:lookback_period]
    yTe = data[nTr:,lookback_period:]

    return xTr, yTr, xTe, yTe

xTr,yTr,xTe,yTe = train_test_split(data=data,lookback_period=lookback,forecast_period=forecast,split = 0.2)

# # Check the split is correct:
random_sample = np.random.randint(0,xTr.shape[0])

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(np.arange(lookback) * delta_t, xTr[random_sample], label='xTr')
plt.plot(np.arange(lookback,timesteps) * delta_t, yTr[random_sample], label='yTr')
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Signal Value")
plt.title(f"Random Sum of Sines with Brownian Motion sample {random_sample}")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Scaling the data
I have read about how scaling features are important for LSTMs, but interestingly if I use min-max scaling I get issues with discontinuity. I.e. for timestep 1501 the LSTM doesn't predict a value close to timestep 1500. But it seems pretty obvious that for the first couple of timesteps in the forecast, the LSTM should learn to predict a value that is close to the last value it has seen.
Multistep LSTM prediction with min-max scaling

It's interesting how the first value the LSTM predicts is no where near the last true value it has seen. Additionally, it predicts this shape for every sample for some reason.
Multistep LSTM prediction with robust scaling

Multistep LSTM prediction with NO scaling

And the LSTM does better with data that is unscaled/only scaled slightly.
Main question I am trying to answer
Why is the LSTM not able to predict well on input data that is scaled to the range 0-1 using min-max scaling(LSTM prediction does not start from the most recent value but is instead discontinuous and the LSTM always predicts the same weird sine like curve for all the input samples)?
What is the cause of the discontinuity issue?
I've attached the PyTorch code I use to build my model below. Am I doing something wrong with my LSTM architecture?
class LSTMUnivariateMultiStep(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, timesteps, features, lstm_units=64, hidden_fc_layers=0, hidden_units=128, forecast_length=1, nn_activation='linear'):
        """
        LSTM Model for univariate time series with multi-step one-shot prediction.

        Parameters:
        - timesteps (int): Number of timesteps in the input sequence.
        - features (int): Number of features at each timestep.
        - lstm_units (int): Number of units in the LSTM layer.
        - forecast_length (int): Number of steps to predict into the future (in one shot).
        - hidden_fc_layers (int): Number of Fully Connected hidden NN layers after the LSTM layer
        - hidden_units (int): Number of nodes in the hidden layers
        - nn_activation (string): Activation to use on the last fully connected output layer
        """
        super(LSTMUnivariateMultiStep, self).__init__()

        self.timesteps = timesteps
        self.features = features
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        assert hidden_fc_layers == 0 or hidden_fc_layers < 3  # only supports 0 or 1 right now
        self.hidden_fc_layers = hidden_fc_layers
        assert nn_activation == 'relu' or nn_activation == 'linear'  # only supports linear or relu now
        self.nn_activation = nn_activation
        self.forecast_length = forecast_length  # Number of timesteps to predict

        # LSTM layer: input_size is features, hidden_size is lstm_units
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=features, hidden_size=lstm_units, batch_first=True)

        # Fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(lstm_units, hidden_units)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_units, hidden_units)
        if hidden_fc_layers > 0:
            self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_units, forecast_length * features)
        else:
            self.output = nn.Linear(lstm_units, forecast_length * features)

    def forward(self, x, return_activations=False):
        """
        Forward pass of the model.

        Parameters:
        - x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor of shape (batch_size, timesteps, features).
        - return_activations (bool): If True, return hidden state activations.

        Returns:
        - torch.Tensor: Predicted output for the next `forecast_length` timesteps,
                        shape (batch_size, forecast_length, features).
        - activations (optional): If `return_activations` is True, returns hidden state activations of shape 
                                  (batch_size, timesteps, lstm_units).
        """
        # Pass input through LSTM layer
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)  # lstm_out shape: (batch_size, timesteps, lstm_units)

        # If requested, return activations (i.e., hidden states for each LSTM unit across timesteps)
        if return_activations:
            return lstm_out

        # Use the output from the last timestep of the LSTM
        last_timestep_output = lstm_out[:, -1, :]  # shape: (batch_size, lstm_units)

        if self.hidden_fc_layers == 1:
            hidden_out = F.relu(self.fc1(last_timestep_output))
        elif self.hidden_fc_layers == 2:
            hidden_out1 = F.relu(self.fc1(last_timestep_output))
            hidden_out = F.relu(self.fc2(hidden_out1))
        else:
            hidden_out = last_timestep_output

        # Pass through the fully connected layer to predict the full forecast
        if self.nn_activation == 'relu':
            fc_output = F.relu(self.output(hidden_out))  # shape: (batch_size, forecast_length * features)
        else:
            fc_output = self.output(hidden_out)

        # Reshape the output to be (batch_size, forecast_length, features)
        output = fc_output.view(-1, self.forecast_length, self.features)

        return output  # shape: (batch_size, forecast_length, features)

When creating the model I do:
lstm_multistep = LSTMUnivariateMultiStep(timesteps=lookback, features=features, lstm_units=64, forecast_length=forecast) #basic multistep LSTM


What exactly is your question?

Sorry let me clarify (edited in original post). My question is why is the LSTM not able to predict well on input data that is scaled to the range 0-1 (LSTM prediction does not start from the most recent value but is instead discontinuous and the LSTM always predicts the same weird sine like curve for all the input samples)?
